# Javascript cryptographic-hash-protected loader

Tags: javascript, cdn, sha

We all know that there are security implications from loading javascript from public CDN networks.  On the other hand, there are benefits in being able to cache these resources.

So obviously there must be a javascript solution to this where an implementation of for example SHA-256 is used to check the integrity of jquery after loading it from a CDN, but before evaluating the javascript.

What are the best options for doing this?

Comment: So how do you suppose this works? Load a trusted JS from your domain, and verify the CDN'ed script? Why not load the script from your domain in the first place? Just set the right expiry, and you won't need CDN anymore.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  The reason for using a public CDN for known scripts is of course to not have to load them in the first place because they are cached in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) is a [W3C draft specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) that does exactly this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-rY/jv8mMhqDabXSo+UCggqKtdmBfd3qC2/KvyTDNQ6PcUJXaxK1tMepoQda4g5vB"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the CDN server is sending [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers, you can retrieve the file with XHR and verify the contents before evaluating it. Note that this is a big change from how the script element is usually executed synchronously:

```
<script src="//google.com/jquery"></script>
<script>//jQuery is available</script>
```

The above will no longer be possible so if you have already written lots of code under the traditional sequential synchronous assumptions it might not be feasible

---

If the CDN server is not sending CORS headers it is not possible to look at the contents. And I suppose any workarounds for this would defeat the purpose.